# .net create a generic method to accept an Interface as Generic

Tags: c#, .net

i was trying to create a generic method to register services and their implementations:
i used this this piece of code

```
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
          .GetTypes()
          .Where(item => item.GetInterfaces()
          .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
          .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>)) && !item.IsAbstract && !item.IsInterface)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(assignedTypes =>
          {
              var serviceType = assignedTypes.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRepository<>));
              services.AddScoped(serviceType, assignedTypes);
          });
```

But how can i actually write this as a generic method?
replacing that "IRepository<>" so that can accept other interfaces ?

Comment: You don't need reflection to write generic methods. The mention of `IRepository<>` is very suspicious - are you trying to implement the "repository-over-EF" antipattern? A DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work, a DbSet already is a single-entity repository. They're higher level abstractions than CRUD classes

Comment: In any case, you can register generic interfaces without specifying the type at all. You can use eg `AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>),typeof(MyLogger<>))`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a generic method by placing a variable name within `<>`, typically `T` is used in generic methods but it's not a hard rule.  `T` here is a `Type` which can be used like any other.  Where you had  `IRepository<>`, replace it with the new type `T`.

Call your method like this:

`SetServices<IRepository<>>()`

```
public void SetServices<T>()
{
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
          .GetTypes()
          .Where(item => item.GetInterfaces()
          .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
          .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(T)) && !item.IsAbstract && !item.IsInterface)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(assignedTypes =>
          {
              var serviceType = assignedTypes.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(T));
              services.AddScoped(serviceType, assignedTypes);
          });
}
```